# Query 2 ElasticSearch from Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to query 2 different ElasticSearch clusters in Spring boot, where the input to 2nd query depends on the result of 1st result. The important things to note here is, these two ES are different versions.

Till now the input to the ES query comes from the web/mobile interface, but, now, this service is dependent on a separate ES cluster for its input.

The different versions cause problems on the library ES versions used in the spring-boot. So What I thought is to use REST client directly to query the ES version that I can use.

Is there a different approach to solve this?

Comment: What are the two versions? Can you update them to the same?

Comment: One being 6.2.x and another, 7.x.x

Answer (score 1):

Running two versions of elasticsearch in a single application is very common although your use-case is bit unique, but ultimately you need to run two versions of Elasticsearch in your application.

Why not you [shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) the ES libraries to avoid the version conflict. You can refer to [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60752410/4039431) on how to do it.